# UITableView empty cells height in a self-sizing table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a self-sizing tableView to create a to-do list exactly as in the native 'Reminder' application. When I add more text in a task row and update the tableView with `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`, tableView resizes not only the corresponding row but all empty cells too. Is it possible to fix these **empty cells heights** without manual calculations? I don't want to rid off the separator, as I want exactly the same look as in the 'Reminder' application, and I hope to avoid manual calculations.

---

I'm not talking about the dynamic height of the cell. It is clear, and it is working fine. I'm talking about **empty** cells, generated automatically (spacers), and their automatic height, which updates as soon as updates the height of the cell, which I edit.

Once again, I'll try to clarify:

1. The cell is editable (contains UITextView).
2. I have **only one** cell in the table, all the rest are just automatic spacers.
3. The tableView updates by `tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates()` as updates the height of the cell with every new line in the UITextView, which I edit. This part works fine.
4. On update, **the tableView changes the size of empty (automatic) cells**, what I don't want, and what doesn't happen in the native iPhone 'Reminder' application.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide some picture about your issue

Comment: I've updated the question with the pictures. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The problem is that I have **only one** cell, so the `UITableView.automaticDimension` 'thinks' that the rest have the same height. You just need to add one more cell to the end. Just `UITableViewCell()`. You can fix its height and add to a separate section for sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Just set **rowHeight** to *automaticDimension* in your code and don't implement **tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614852-rowheight

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help in that case. The automaticDimension changes spacers height as well, based on the first cell.

Comment: Weird, let me check with a sample project.

Comment: Yeah you are right, _automaticDimension_ assumes the height of all the empty cells after the last cell are equal to the height of the last cell, which kind of makes sense also to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code snippet:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension 
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Reference Link - 
http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-automatic-row-height/

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help in that case. The tableView changes spacers based on the first cell.

Answer (score 0):

its better you compute cells height according input text
you can use this extension for compute label height by considering text and font

```
 extension UILabel {

    func retrieveTextHeight () -> CGFloat {
        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:self.font])

        let rect = attributedText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

        return ceil(rect.size.height)
    }

}
```

use this extension in this way

```
 yourTableViewCellHeight = self.label.retrieveTextHeight()
```

don't forget add your margin to this height

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to avoid manual calculations? I'm going to have a more sophisticated layout of the cell and reflect some additional information so that manual calculations can be a little bit tricky.

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov if you want do it by story board you can put stack view inside your table view cell then insert your label inside the stack view and make your label number of line  = 0

Comment: thank you. I have already found a solution. The problem is not in the sizing of the cell itself, but in the size of empty cells. Thank you again for your time.